# Error extraño con Objeto null - Java- SpringBoot - Primefaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, primefaces

Me encuentro realizando un sistema sencillo que permita agregar preguntas para un cuestionario, el problema viene cuando se guarda la pregunta ya que no detecta los valores introducidor desde la vista `bancoPrueba.xhtml`

Contexto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar click en guarda pregunta no ocurre nada ni en la consola

ahora bien la vista es esta:

```
<p:dialog header="Crear pregunta" showEffect="fade" modal="true" id="dialogPregunta" widgetVar="manageProductDialog"
                  responsive="true">
            <h:form id="dialogs">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:outputPanel id="manage-product-content" class="ui-fluid">
                        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty crudView.pregunta}">
                            <div class="field">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Titulo:" for="tituloPregunta"/>
                                <p:inputText type="text" id="tituloPregunta" value="#{crudView.pregunta.titulo}"
                                             required="true"/>
                                <p:message for="tituloPregunta"/>

                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Descripcion:" for="descripcionPregunta"/>
                                <p:inputText type="text" id="descripcionPregunta" value="#{crudView.pregunta.descripcion}"
                                             required="true"/>
                                <p:message for="descripcionPregunta"/>

                            </div>


                            <div class="field">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Categoria(s):" for="categoriasList"/>
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="categoriasList" value="#{crudView.pregunta.categoria}"
                                                 required="true" converter="#{categoriaConverter}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione la categoria"/>
                                    <f:selectItems var="categorias" itemLabel="#{categorias.titulo}"
                                                   value="#{crudView.categoriasList}"/>
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <p:message for="categoriasList"/>
                            </div>


                            <div class="formgrid grid">
                                <div class="field col">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="Pregunta activa?:" />
                                    <br/>
                                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="activaPr" value="#{crudView.value}"
                                                             itemLabel="Marcar / Desmarcar"/>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Opciones" />
                            <p:selectOneListbox id="opcionesList" value="#{crudView.opcionList}"
                                                required="true" converter="#{opcionConverter}">
                                <f:selectItems var="opcion" itemLabel="#{opcion.descripcion}"
                                               value="#{crudView.opcionList}"/>
                            </p:selectOneListbox>

                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:outputPanel>


                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton onclick="PF('crearOpcion').show()" update="@form" value="Crear opcion"
                                         icon="pi pi-plus"/>
                        <p:growl for="msjBean" showDetail="true"/>
                        <br/>



                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{crudView.savePregunta}" value="Crear pregunta"  icon="pi pi-check" type="submit" id="submitButton"
                                         process="@this"  />
                        <p:growl for="msjBean" showDetail="true"/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="pi pi-times"
                                         onclick="PF('manageProductDialog').hide()"
                                         class="ui-button-secondary" type="button"/>
                        <p:growl for="msjBean" showDetail="true"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Resultado debugg a mi clase controladora `CrudView.java`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase `crudView`:

```
public class CrudView implements Serializable {

@Value(value = "#{seguridadBean.profesorSesion}")
private Profesor personaSesion;
@Getter
@Setter
private boolean value, value2;

@Inject
PreguntaServicio preguntaServicio;
@Inject
ProfesorServicio profesorServicio;

@Getter
@Setter
private List<Pregunta> preguntasList;

@Getter
@Setter
private List<Opcion> opcionList;


@Getter
@Setter
private List<Categorias> categoriasList;

@Getter
@Setter
private Opcion opcion;
@Getter
@Setter
private Pregunta pregunta;

@Getter
@Setter
private Categorias categoria;

private List<Pregunta> selectedPreguntas;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    opcion = new Opcion();
    pregunta = new Pregunta();
    opcionList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.preguntasList = this.preguntaServicio.preguntasList();
    this.categoriasList = this.profesorServicio.obtenerCategorias();
    System.out.println("ENTRO INIT  -------------------"+pregunta.getDescripcion()+pregunta.getTitulo());
}

public List<Pregunta> getSelectedPreguntas() {
    return selectedPreguntas;
}

public void setSelectedPreguntas(List<Pregunta> selectedPreguntas) {
    this.selectedPreguntas = selectedPreguntas;
}



// Guardar pregunta
public String savePregunta() throws Exception {




    if (opcionList.size() > 0) {
        try {


            pregunta.setOpcionList(opcionList);
            pregunta.setEsVisible(value);
            pregunta.setCategoria(categoria);


            opcionList.forEach(opc -> {
                opc.setPregunta(pregunta);
            });
            pregunta.setOpcionList(opcionList);




            this.preguntasList.add(this.pregunta);
            preguntaServicio.registrarPregunta(pregunta);
            opcion = new Opcion();



            FacesMessage mensaje = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exitoso", "Pregunta creada con éxito");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msjBean", mensaje);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesMessage mensaje = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Alerta", e.getMessage());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msjBean", mensaje);
        }
    } else {
        FacesMessage mensaje = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Alerta", "Es obligatorio crear opciones");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msjBean", mensaje);
    }


    return "true;";
}
```

Ahora bien he llegado quizas a la conclusion de que puede ser la forma en como capturo los datos en el formulario de crearPregunta alguna ayuda este problema un poco tedioso lo agradeceria!

Comment: Hola, creo que confundes los datos de `this.pregunta` y `pregunta`, revisa como están funcionando tus variables locales y las del controlador en tu función `savePregunta()`, espero mi comentario te sirva de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, no logro solucionarlo aun :(